# Как сделать высоту блока до нижней границы родительского блока

Tags: html, css

Ситуация такая:
Изначально не мог сделать блок `body` на всё окно браузера (который, как я понимаю, должен быть изначально растянут по краям окна браузера), эта проблема решилась использованием свойства `min-height: 100vh;`

Внутри блока `body` у меня есть блок `main` который я также хочу растянуть на все окно. С этим опять же может помочь `min-height: 100vh;` Но ***100vh*** это размер относительно окна, а когда я пишу `min-height: 100%` то между низом окна (и получается границей блока `body`) и границей блока `main` появляется огромная пустая область, хотя по идее т.к я использую ***%*** он должен расположить блок main по всей высоте блока body и данной области быть не должно...  Также пустая область исчезает если увеличить контент внутри блока main (как раз таки, за счет увеличения области блока main). Подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего эта пустая область появляется?

```css
body {
  background: #ffe3e3;
  margin: 0px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  background: #3604bf;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  top: 0px;
}

main {
  background: #ff9ebb;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

article {
  margin: auto;
}

#container-latin {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#container-standart {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h4>h4</h4>
</nav>
<main>
  <h1>h1</h1>
  <div id="container-latin">
    <article>
      <h3>h3</h3>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=foto" alt="photo">
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>h3</h3>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=foto" alt="photo ">
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>h3</h3>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=foto" alt="photo">
    </article>
  </div>
  <div id="container-standart">
    <article>
      <h3>h3</h3>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=foto" alt="photo ">
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>h3</h3>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=foto" alt="photo">
    </article>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image: Скрин с пустой областью]

[image: Область блока body]

[image: Область блока main]

Comment: пример кода покажите - я по русскому плохо понимаю

Comment: @MaximLensky Добавил

Comment: Я проблемы, описанной в вопросе, не наблюдаю...

Comment: @Air Добавил скрины как у меня... Кстати, при увеличении размера страницы эта область пропадает, ну или как я написал в вопросе: при добавлении контента (если фото достаточно большие) блок main автоматически увеличится и пустой зоны не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Семён, наблюдаю, как Вы мучаетесь уже несколько часов с одним вопросом. Отвечаю на Ваш вопрос: чтобы растянуть дочерний блок по высоте на `100%`, необходимо родительскому блоку, а также до самого и включительно `body` и `html` также указать высоту `100%`. При необходимости для родительского блока нужно указать `overflow: hidden` Вот пример:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

.wrp {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrp"></div>
</div>
```